# Do I need to get 32 bits composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, 32-bit

I am using Windows 10 (32bit), but I can't find a 32bit version of composer.

I found the [download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/) but I don't know if there is a 32bit version I can download.

Are 32 bits operative systems supported?

Answer (score 2):

Composer is neither "32" nor "64" bits. It's just another PHP script.

It runs on whatever PHP runtime is installed on your system. If PHP runs on your system (and the appropriate extensions are installed), composer will work.